# SSL on wordpress with non-SSL elements

Tags: ssl, wordpress

I have a website built using by default using Http protocol , and I'd like to turn it to HTTPS for security purposes.

But, I have a lot of articles (more than 1000) with non-ssl elements like **iframe**, **images** from **other** **sites** etc...

How can I make it works? I see that CSS and JS are not loading because it use the HTTP link...

I know I can change the header, it's easy but what about these articles?

Is there a plugins that convert **http://** to **https//** ?

Comment: The easiest way for this might be to have apache redirect all http requests to https. Of course only applies if you want all your pages & resources be served via HTTPS

Comment: And what about the iframes from others sites.. ? :/

Comment: I've seen the [Search and Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin mentioned on a lot of forums for this kind of issue.

Comment: For other sites there is the issue if they actually support SSL. So a simple replacement for external resources is dangerous as it might break stuff.

Comment: I cannot be sure that every site i used on the article support SSL :/